# "Blur" Positions with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to create a Geometry Nodes setup which would "blur" or even out the positions of a set of instances. I had the idea to run the position node through a Blur Attribute and connect it into the Position input of a Set Position node. But that doesn't do anything.

This is a simplified version of what I was attempting. My hope was that "blurring" the Y axis would cause the objects to line up in the Y axis given high enough blur iterations.

[image]

I am not sure if the question makes sense. Let me know if clarification is necessary.

Comment: That should work. What is your complete node setting? But if they are instances, they cannot be changed as instances.

Comment: Please share the the nodes you have as far, and a [.blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/).

Comment: _Blur_ needs some notion of neighbours.. so will work only on meshes and curves, as I understand it. That blur-able geometry could originate in the way the instances were originally distributed, or be reconstructed, .  The former would be easier, if available.. how were the instances distributed in the first place?

Comment: @RobinBetts yeah, I also imagined that "neighbours" might be necessary. I edited the original post a bit. As you can see my "instances" are actually a bunch of objects in a collection. So I guess it is the more complicated case from the two you mentioned.

Comment: why don't you just set Y from median point?

Comment: @Crantisz Honestly, I have no idea what that means. :)

Comment: @CGDive look at the answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can set median point position in Y coordinate for each instance:

[image]